# Can this type checks with "object" be improved?

Tags: javascript, equals, equality, typeof, type-coercion

```
if (typeof a !== "object" && typeof b !== "object") {
    return a == b;
}
... // check pairwise equality of object a & b using `for in`
```

Is it the same as

```
if (typeof a !== "object") {
    return a == b;
}
```

Is there any `b` with `typeof b === "object"` which would change the semantics?

Are there any horrible edge cases I should be aware of? Comparisons between an `object` and a `native type` which have a non-intuitive boolean equality or disequality? Including any bugs in browser (I mean you IE6!)

Comment: It depends what you're concerned with, for example `var a = "[object Object]";` and `var b = {}` would be equal in your second check, but not the first.

Comment: @NickCraver yikes! That's a horrid side effect! Basically I was worried of Objects being equal to such things.

Comment: @Nick: write that in an answer, because it is: "[object Object]" == {}, answers this line: Is there any `b` with `typeof b === "object"` which would change the semantics?

Comment: remember javascript has automatic type conversion - you could counter this by doing `a===b` if you wanted

Comment: @MartinJespersen I know what I'm doing with type coercion (partly) Just wanted to find horrid edge cases like the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second check is not *quite* the same as the first, no, simply because JavaScript is weakly typed so at the very least consider the "`.toString()` effect", as well as others.  For example these would fail the first check, but pass in the second:

```
var a = "[object Object]";
var b = {};
```

Or, a bit simpler (showing a case you may want to consider...but this passes both checks):

```
var a = 0;
var b = "0";
```

One fix would be to do a value *and* type check with `===` [which is a strict comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators), you get type checking as well...but I'm not *entirely* sure that's what you're after, since the current check is explicitly "not an object".

Comment: cmon Nick. At least give me the benefit of the doubt that I know how type coercion works and the difference between `==` & `===` ;)

Comment: @Raynos - bear in mind all answers will be seen by many *others*, actually very rarely is *all* of my answer soley for the OP, please take no offense :)

Comment: I know, just felt a bit patronising. It's fine. everyone needs to remember the horrors of type coercion. Especially since the edge cases are non-intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

it's not the same.
here's an example to understand why :

```
var a = "a string";
var b = new String("a string");
console.log(typeof a);//"string" !== "object"
console.log(typeof b);//"object" === "object"
console.log('"' + a + '" ' + (a==b?"==":"!=") + ' "' + b + '"');
```

the same thing can happen for numbers :

```
var a = 1;
var b = new Number(1);
```

your two if statements are not the same for the obvious reason.
you could "improve" your type check by using the `instanceof` operator to suite tour needs :

```
if ((typeof a !== "object" || a instanceof Number || a instanceof String) &&
    (typeof b !== "object" || b instanceof Number || b instanceof String))
    return a == b;
```

Comment: @Raynos: If all you want is to check simple types, just check weather the prototype property is present on a & b ;) `if(!a.prototype && !b.prototype) { return a==b; }`

Comment: @MartinJespersen I actaully want to implement [`assert.deepEqual`](https://github.com/Raynos/BrowserCJS/blob/master/Modules/assert/assert1.0.js) from CommonJS which is a bit "buggy".

Comment: @Raynos: in that case, don't skimp on checks... do typeofs on everything and no coersion at all

Comment: @MartinJespersen the spec says resort to type coercion :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [isEqual](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#isEqual) from [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). It "Performs an optimized deep comparison between the two objects, to determine if they should be considered equal." It works for all types of variables. This is how it's implemented:

```
  // Perform a deep comparison to check if two objects are equal.
  _.isEqual = function(a, b) {
    // Check object identity.
    if (a === b) return true;
    // Different types?
    var atype = typeof(a), btype = typeof(b);
    if (atype != btype) return false;
    // Basic equality test (watch out for coercions).
    if (a == b) return true;
    // One is falsy and the other truthy.
    if ((!a && b) || (a && !b)) return false;
    // Unwrap any wrapped objects.
    if (a._chain) a = a._wrapped;
    if (b._chain) b = b._wrapped;
    // One of them implements an isEqual()?
    if (a.isEqual) return a.isEqual(b);
    // Check dates' integer values.
    if (_.isDate(a) && _.isDate(b)) return a.getTime() === b.getTime();
    // Both are NaN?
    if (_.isNaN(a) && _.isNaN(b)) return false;
    // Compare regular expressions.
    if (_.isRegExp(a) && _.isRegExp(b))
      return a.source     === b.source &&
             a.global     === b.global &&
             a.ignoreCase === b.ignoreCase &&
             a.multiline  === b.multiline;
    // If a is not an object by this point, we can't handle it.
    if (atype !== 'object') return false;
    // Check for different array lengths before comparing contents.
    if (a.length && (a.length !== b.length)) return false;
    // Nothing else worked, deep compare the contents.
    var aKeys = _.keys(a), bKeys = _.keys(b);
    // Different object sizes?
    if (aKeys.length != bKeys.length) return false;
    // Recursive comparison of contents.
    for (var key in a) if (!(key in b) || !_.isEqual(a[key], b[key])) return false;
    return true;
  };
```

See the [Underscore.js source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/underscore.js) to see the rest of the functions used by this one.

It's easy to miss some edge cases so I would recommend using a well tested code like this one instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: way ahead of you. I took most of my function from that source :). Shamefully it does not satisfy the CommonJS specification.